# why this is showing error while running yarn command

Tags: javascript, yarn-v2

The pinterest clone in which when i run yarn start that error show

```
PS D:\Pintest\cp-live-pinterest-clone-master> yarn start  
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:571
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in D:\Pintest\cp-live-pinterest-clone-master\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss\package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:361:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:697:9)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:565:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:634:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Pintest\cp-live-pinterest-clone-master\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\lib\safe-parser.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I try again install yarn try all possible things which i can